# Migrating from enzyme to react-testing-library: how to select the nth element from list

Tags: javascript, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have this code:

```
wrapper.find('.table-year-head button').at(1).simulate('click');
wrapper
  .find('.table-months')
  .at(1)
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach(node => {
    expect(node.props().checked).toEqual(true);
});
```

I know that I can use `data-testid` for the selectors but how can I select the nth?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [getAllBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#types-of-queries) query:

```js
const table = wrapper.getAllByRole('table')[1]
fireEvent.click(within(table).getByRole('button'));
```

The problem is that you wouldn't be able to use CSS selectors the way you are doing with Enzyme. React testing library is all about semantic. I would recommend you to add labels to your tables using [aria-label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/table_role) attribute:

```js
<table className="years" aria-label="Year table">
...
```

This way, you would be able to do:

```js
const yearTable = wrapper.getByRole('table', {name: 'Year table'});
fireEvent.click(within(yearTable).getByRole('button'));

const monthTable = screen.getByRole('table', {name: 'February table'});
const checkbox = within(monthTable).getByRole('checkbox')
fireEvent.click(checkbox);
expect(checkbox).toBeChecked();
```